# What is the technique of factoring the difference of two polynomials, and what does this tell you?

Tags: polynomials

If given two polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, factoring the difference of the two polynomials give you $F(x) = P(x) - Q(x)$. Apparently, this tells you the nature of the intersections between these two curves but I do not understand why. Could someone explain in relatively simple terms?

Additionally, when would you use this technique?

Comment: This technique is often used when it is conceptually easier to look for when one function is zero than when two functions are equal. As for how to understand it, perhaps you could reflect on what it means that the graphs of two functions intersect?

Comment: The two functions intersect when they are equal to one another. I guess if you move one polynomial to the other side, effectively having P(x) - Q(x) = 0???

Comment: Yeah, that sounds just about right.

Comment: The question stems from : If a and b are non zero and a + b = 0, prove that $A(x) = x^3 -ax^2 -x +b$ and $B(x) = x^3 + bx^2 -x + a$ have a common factor but are not identical polynomials. I used factoring the difference to solve the question, but I do not know how to prove they are not identical. $(a - b)(x^2 -1)$, would they not be identical if they share the same roots?